# How to start an independent process on the jvm

Tags: java, process, child-process, spawn

I am writing a docker entry point program that runs on the jvm (using scala), that performs some configuration then starts another process. I'd like the jvm process to do the configuration, launch the other process, then exit. But have the other process, that was launched by the jvm, stick around.

This only needs to work on Linux, so shell commands are acceptable.

I have tried the following commands, using Runtime.exec and process builder. However, when the jvm exited the launched process also exited.

```
sh -c nohup <my program> &
nohup sh -c <my program> &
nohup <my program> &
<my program> &
<my program>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does *"with no success"* mean?

Comment: When the jvm exited, the launched process also exited. I updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: I ever implemented similar function in Solaris. My final solution is telnet to local server, execute command `nohup <cmd> &` then logout.